# Joomla! K2 - How to fetch Author Item Count for user page?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

I have several authors on my website and each of them has a page of his own with his image, description and a list of all his items. I would like to add an "Item Counter" to their pages, so the page will look like this:

author name, **number of posts** -> author description -> author items.

The only thing i miss here is the number of posts by the author.

Thank you so much for the answers!

Comment: lots of incorrect PHP..

Comment: Please share some of the code you have tried and we can help you adapt it to suit your needs

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help. what i tried so far is basically to count the items on the page with:
<?php echo count($this->items);  ?>

this is not good enough because i have a pagination here and it counts the items not including the pagination.

Do you have any idea how to count also the pagination items? thanks!

Comment: Update: I managed to count also the pagination items but seperatly with:
($this->pagination->total)

how do i combine the counts? 
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to slightly modify the K2 view (we did this to one of our clients). You will need to create a query that resembles the following in the view:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM #__k2_items WHERE authorid='id';
```

Now you should pass the result of that query to the template (using the assignRef function on the $this object. That's it!

Note: not sure about the field name authorid, I'm sure it's something else but I can't remember it on top of my head.